# Form with only 10 buttons but user can choose only 1

Tags: html, forms

im trying to make a form with a title, paragraph and a score out of 10. I would like make to make only one button go into database. How can i do that and conserve the current style of my buttons ?

## example

## User selects a button

button 1

button 2 //user chooses this button on click

## User change selected button

button 1 //user changes the selected button on click

button 2

.

And when i click submit it sends button 1 into database

code:

```
        <form method="POST" action="index.php?action=sendReview" class="redaction" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div id="scores">
              <input class="score" type="button" name="options" style="color:red;" value="1" id="option1"> 
              <input class="score" type="button" name="options" style="color:red;" value="2"id="option2"> 
              <input class="score" type="button" name="options" style="color:red;" value="3"id="option3"> 
              <input class="score" type="button" name="options" style="color:orange;" value="4" id="option4"> 
              <input class="score" type="button" name="options"  style="color:orange;"value="5"id="option5"> 
              <input class="score" type="button" name="options" style="color:orange;" value="6"id="option6"> 
              <input class="score" type="button" name="options" style="color:orange;" value="7"id="option7"> 
              <input class="score"type="button" name="options" style="color:green;" value="8"id="option8"> 
              <input class="score" type="button" name="options" style="color:green;" value="9" id="option9"> 
              <input class="score" type="button" name="options" style="color:green;" value="10" id="option10"> 
            </div>
            <input type="text"name="nameReview" class="nameReview"placeholder="Review Title">
            <textarea id="story" name="review-content"rows="5" cols="33" placeholder="Write your Review here"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Publish" name="review" class="publish">
        </form>
```

How it looks like

[image: How it needs to look]

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `<input type="radio">` and style them like buttons?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your value in a hidden input. On submit of the form you can get this value by the name of the hidden field.

See below example, It will post `userScore` as a user selected score.

```js
$(".score").click(function(){
  var btnId = $(this).val();
  $("#userScore").val(btnId);
  console.log($("#userScore").val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="index.php?action=sendReview" class="redaction" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div id="scores">
              <input class="score" type="button" name="options" style="color:red;" value="1" id="option1"> 
              <input class="score" type="button" name="options" style="color:red;" value="2"id="option2"> 
              <input class="score" type="button" name="options" style="color:red;" value="3"id="option3"> 
              <input class="score" type="button" name="options" style="color:orange;" value="4" id="option4"> 
              <input class="score" type="button" name="options"  style="color:orange;"value="5"id="option5"> 
              <input class="score" type="button" name="options" style="color:orange;" value="6"id="option6"> 
              <input class="score" type="button" name="options" style="color:orange;" value="7"id="option7"> 
              <input class="score"type="button" name="options" style="color:green;" value="8"id="option8"> 
              <input class="score" type="button" name="options" style="color:green;" value="9" id="option9"> 
              <input class="score" type="button" name="options" style="color:green;" value="10" id="option10"> 
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="userScore" id="userScore">
            <input type="text"name="nameReview" class="nameReview"placeholder="Review Title">
            <textarea id="story" name="review-content"rows="5" cols="33" placeholder="Write your Review here"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Publish" name="review" class="publish">
        </form>
```